# Cloud sql with Mobile Backend Starter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

After reading about Mobile Backend Starter it talks about using it with App engine Datastore but not Google cloud sql. When setting up your new project with Mobile Backend Starter can you specify that you want to use Google Cloud sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mobile Backend Starter uses the Datastore by default, but it would be simple to alter it to use Cloud SQL. This is a good starting point:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide